# Deflection of the pendulum arm in Cavendish experiment

Tags: experimental-physics, newton

I'm trying to find how Cavendish calculated the deflection of the arm due to the gravitational attractions of the weights.

He gives for the deflection B=6.18 divisions. "Motion of the arm on moving weights from negatif to positif position = 6.18" (Experiment 4, page 487 in [Cavendish's paper](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/pdf/10.1098/rstl.1798.0022))

How did he get the number B=6.18 divisions?

Comment: I tried to add "cavendish-experiment" as a new tag but I didn't have enough reputation. Can someone add it? There are 150 questions about the Cavendish experiment.

Answer (score 1):

Cavendish takes the difference of the positions of the "Point of rest" before and after he moves the weights. So when the weights are in positive position, the point of rest is at $24.9$ divisions. He moves the weights to negative position and the first position of the point of rest is $18.72$ divisions and $24.9-18.72=6.18$